# Serving python pyramid app on a windows ec2 intance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, pyramid

I am trying to serve a website I built with python pyramid on an amazon ec2 instance.

Running locally is fine and I have run it on an internal server that works fine, but when I run it on a windows ec2 instance, it times out waiting to connect. (Specifically "The connection to **.**.**.*** was interrupted." (using chrome))

The issues that I have researched generally involve port 80 not being open, however I have added port 80 to the inbound rules.

I have tried serving on the internal ip of the instance and 0.0.0.0, but to no avail.

Are there any steps I am missing? What other errors could there be?

There has been mention of inefficiencies with serving python app directly, but as it is only small internal use I am not concerned. Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Comment: We need more information before we can even try answering this question. 1. Are you able to connect to it locally from the machine it is running on? 2. Have you opened port 80 on EC2's rules? 3. Is the Windows firewall blocking the incoming request? 4. Are you sure pserve is running?